# Integrate Camunda with LDAP

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, camunda

I’m trying to integrate cockpit with LDAP.

I’m following this tutorial: https://dzone.com/articles/open-ldap-and-camunda-integration-in-windows

For testing purpose I’m using online ldap: https://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/

I have configured WebSecurityConfig like this:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }


    @Bean
    public static AdministratorAuthorizationPlugin administratorAuthorizationPlugin() {

        AdministratorAuthorizationPlugin plugin = new AdministratorAuthorizationPlugin();

        plugin.setAdministratorUserName("gauss");
        return plugin;

    }



    @Bean
    public static LdapIdentityProviderPlugin ldapIdentityProviderPlugin() {
        LdapIdentityProviderPlugin plugin = new LdapIdentityProviderPlugin();
        plugin.setServerUrl("ldap://ldap.forumsys.com");
        plugin.setManagerDn("cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com");
        plugin.setManagerPassword("password");
        plugin.setBaseDn("ou=mathematicians,dc=example,dc=com");
        plugin.setUserSearchBase("");
        plugin.setUserSearchFilter("(objectclass=person)");
        plugin.setUserIdAttribute("uid");
        plugin.setUserFirstnameAttribute("cn");
        plugin.setUserLastnameAttribute("sn");
        plugin.setUserPasswordAttribute("userPassword");
        return plugin;
    }
```

However this results in: `Login Failed : Wrong credentials, locked user or missing access rights to application`

I’m not sure where I’m wrong, it seems that it is authorizing user in ldap, but some rights are missing for user “gauss”, even thou I have granted him administrator privileges, what am I missing?

Comment: ServerUrl need to be : ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389/